# GitHub API search optional keywords

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to use the GitHub search repository API, but I want to use optional search keywords (e.g. include mutltiple terms and match on best match, rather than only match on repos that have all terms - so if i search java,node,javascript, if no project is marked as all three it returns repos with partial matches).

Not much is given away in the docs: http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories

I have tried a few variations of delimiters (,+ ||) but they all seem to asses keywords as AND (API example is https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/java,groovy,spring)

Anyone else have experience of this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there are no search operators (AND, OR, NOT) available for GitHub search, both for the web app and the API. I suggest you make a feature request by sending an e-mail to GitHub support: support@github.com. Not much you can do other than that.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am starting to think as well - After a quick look it looks like the site search on github works the same way. I have contacted the api team so will update if they come back with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API search functionality is from v2 of the API. At that time, GitHub search was really suboptimal and it has since significantly improved thanks to the awesome team over there. Unfortunately, that hasn't improved the API search so, that is still tied to other functionality.